# View query result in table bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am categorizing the time into morning and night and count. But quite confuse how to use it just to view the result in a form of table.

Code:

```
 SELECT
      COUNTIF(time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00') AS morning_events,
      COUNTIF(time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00') AS night_events
    FROM (
      SELECT
        TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS Time
      FROM table
    );
```

So far I managed to get the count function (refer 1st pic) but not sure how can view second table that showing the list of each session (morning/night) for EACH time (refer 2nd pic).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know which criteria you are using to define afternoon and evening but considering only day and night you could do something like this:

```
SELECT time, 
case
  when  time BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '12:00:00' 
  then  "morning"
  when  time < '04:00:00' OR time > '20:00:00' 
  then  "night"
  # You can add other conditions here
  else "nothing"
end
FROM (
      SELECT
        TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Request_Timestamp), SECOND) AS Time
      FROM table
    );
```

Comment: If i wanna grouping the time based on User ID , should i put it in the nested query? tried, but error saying SELECT list expression references column Request_Timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Comment: Did you put the request_timestamp in your group by clause?

Comment: No. put it as GROUP BY function ,it is possible to do so? the results are supposed return the session per user ID (REFER pic in EDITED QUESTION).

Comment: What exactly did you try? If you have a normal field named user_id you just need to add it in your query

Comment: If this field is inside the table queried in the subquery, you should select this field in the subquery too

Comment: ok. i got it. Thanks. I mislook some function and its find now